# RichText options on comments?

Tags: support

Which RichText options are available on the comments field?

Comment: __This__, _that_, `thus`.  Do you need anything else?

Comment: markdown editing help for [Comment Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: It is also in one of the FAQs, *[How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756)*, "How can I format and link in comments?"

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing a comment, there is a "help" link that shows you the following text:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  `[link](http://example.com)` `_italic_` `**bold**` `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work. [Learn more…](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

> [image: screenshot]

(Please ignore the "auto" link, which is added by a script running on my browser.)

The "Learn more" link takes you to the [Markdown help for the comments formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: ops, never paid attention to **it**!